# Javascript target an item in an array

Tags: javascript

How would I target "data" in this array?

```
var waterBarData = {
labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June"],
datasets: [
    {
        label: "My Second dataset",
        fillColor: "rgba(98,203,49,1.0)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(98,203,49,0.8)",
        highlightFill: "rgba(98,203,49,0.75)",
        highlightStroke: "rgba(98,203,49,1)",
        data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27]
    }
]};
```

My guess is below but that doesn't seem to be working

```
waterBarData.datasets[data]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`datasets` in your object is an array so that you need to access it by index:

```
waterBarData.datasets[0]['data'];

// or using dot notation
waterBarData.datasets[0].data;
```